# Android error message explanation please

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

Could someone explain what the error message bellow means? The error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Comment: your using `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.someid)` but in fact View hidden by this id is `ImageButton` ...

Answer (score 5):

You might be doing ..

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

where view is an image button..

so now it cannot cast image button to TextView.. change it to

```
ImageButton button= (ImageButton )findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an object that is an ImageButton (maybe from `findViewById()` ?), and you are trying to make a TextView out of it ("casting"). It might look something like this

```
TextView yourView = (TextView) findViewById('yourButtonView');
```

And you can't do that